# Возможно ли вызвать командную строку Windows внутри jаr файла

Tags: java, консоль

Да, вопрос глупый, ведь java кросплатформенная, а я хочу запустить командную строку Windows. Но всё же, расскажу по порядку.
Создал консольную программу

```
public class NameGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
    }
}
```

Скомпилировал её в jar файл NameGenerator.jar 
Теперь cmd.exe, java -jar Путь/до/файла/NameGenerator.jar 
Ура, работает.
Какие ещё есть инструменты для работы с консольными приложениями? Нельзя ли как-то внутри программы открыть cmd.exe? 
Пока что самым удобным способом для меня является создание батника

```
java -jar NameGenerator.jar
CMD /Q /K
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если попробовать вызвать её через Runtime.exec("cmd.exe"), если не ошибаюсь в написании? Путь, если понадобится. Только там есть хитрость - если не ошибаюсь, надо будет дополнительно привязать поток ввода, сейчас не вспомню, как именно, но гугл поможет

Comment: да, спасибо. Кстати, загуглив Runtime.exec нашёл свой вопрос на stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734416/how-can-cmd-exe-be-launched-from-java